# MiniMagic and Carrierwave on Rails (Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a some problems. And I know, what i'm not alone on it. I'm trying to use carrierwave and minimagic to add an images on my project (blog), but its return this: Image translation missing:

```
"ru.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error"
```

I allready instelled ImageMagick on my machine, and after that install the gems.

My form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @post, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
```

And my model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates :title, :summary, :body, presence: true
end
```

I never used this gems before, and now i really don't know what to do. I install a last version of ImageMagic. I heard that its a popular problem on Windows. May somebody can help a student?

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE7vD.png)

Comment: C'mon guys. Maybe some ideas or smth?? Over 3 days i cant find an answer. ((((

Answer (score 0):

see **[this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2102)** similar issue and [this](http://www.kahfei.com/2017/02/05/carrierwave-mini-magick-error/) (specifically for windows, you might need that package)